# Does Psionic Body work with Metapsionic Feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, psionics

Straight Forward Question:

Psionic Body (XPH. p.49) is a psionic feat allowing a bonus of +2 hit points per psionic feat you have, including itself. Does Psionic body count Metapsionic Feats as being Psionic Feats for this total?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no.

But it really should, and everyone I know let's them do so. Psionic Body is really not a good feat (it’s difficult to even beat Improved Toughness, which is a pretty mediocre feat).

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those sad quirks in the rules. Be it the SRD or the original books, while psionic item creation feats and metapsionic feats are both generally considered to be sub-categories of psionic feats by virtually everyone who uses psionics, no where that I can recall explicitly states it in just that way.

Comment: @nijineko Not really sure how to take your comment: it sounds like you’re agreeing with me, but then you didn’t upvote. Is there something you were recommending I add to the answer?

Comment: I don't think so. I was just commenting. I think I didn't upvote because I was waiting to see if there were more answers coming.